# rails recurring event with whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have a winner controller which have a

```
before_action :set_winners
  def create

    Winner.create(
    date: Time.now,
    likes: winner.selfy.likes_count,
    user_id: winner.user.id,
    selfy_id: winner.selfy.id
    )
  end
private

def set_winners
  date = DateTime.now.utc
  likes = Like.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', 2.week.ago.beginning_of_week, 1.week.ago.end_of_week).select(:selfy_id)
  top = Selfy.where(id: likes)
  top.order("COALESCE(likes_count, 0) DESC").limit(1)
end
```

i want this to be perform every 5 minutes, i try to use whenever gem like this

```
every 2.minutes do
#   command "/usr/bin/some_great_command"
   runner "Winner.create"
#   rake "some:great:rake:task"
 end
```

am getting this error

```
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
```

what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Getting the error when you do what?

Comment: from the whenever cronjob

Comment: Can you run a controller method as a cronjob, isn't that only for model methods?

Comment: alright, therefore better to use rake file i guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
  env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
```

to the top of your schedule.rb file.

Comment: this generate cronjob

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: 
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/geniuskid/rails/selfiestar && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Winner.create'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

```
still returns comman not found

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
```